# Meaning of "the sense of family"

Tags: phrase-meaning, literature

> They knew each other well, the Captain and his wife. They had in
> common a certain way of life, an order of priorities and concerns. Their
> shared experience of death when they were young had drawn them close
> and in their marriage had made precious for them **the sense of family** that
> the birth of a child allowed.

Dose it mean: having only one child was right and good in their family?

Source: The Story of Lucy Gault by William trevor

Answer (score 1):

It says ***sense*** of family. The child gave them ***the feeling, the awareness, the conscience*** that now they are a family. You could also understand that the birth of their child gave them a ***purpose*** to (continue to) exist as a family.

Answer (score 0):

The arrival of their first child had changed them from a couple into a family.

Comment: many thanks, can we say the whole sentence mean: having a child to make a family was really valuable for them because of their shared experience of death?

Comment: I haven't read the book so I don't know the background of the characters, but if they had both lost close family members when they were young, it could well mean that.